Maximizing the KL Divergence when it is Bounded
I've recently been working on trying to find the "worst" possible model, in the Kullback-Leibler (KL) divergence sense, to look at the robustness of an underlying algorithm. I was wondering if there is a known solution to a problem of the form
\begin{equation}
  \arg \max_{\Delta \pi} D_{KL}[ q(x) || p(x)] \ ,
\end{equation}
where $x \in \mathbb{X} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, $p(x) = (1-\varepsilon) \pi(x) + \varepsilon \Delta \pi(x)$, $\pi$ is the "nominal" model, and $0 < \varepsilon \leq 1$ is some fixed probability of sampling the "contaminating" distribution, $\Delta \pi(x)$. If one assumes $\pi$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $q$, the KL divergence should be bounded (or are there other assumptions that need to be made for this to be true?). Additionally, I'm assuming that $\mathbb{E}_\pi\{ x \} = \mathbb{E}_{\Delta \pi} \{ x \}$, such that $p(x)$ is unbiased (with respect to the model, $\pi$). I want to use the KL divergence because it aligns with the variational inference methods I'm ultimately using to define $q$, but I'm interested in whether there is a better approach.
My intuition tells me that $\Delta \pi$ should be a uniform pdf on $\mathbb{X}$, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

I don't think the answer should be uniform: the goal of $\Delta$ is to make $p$ look like $q$, and so if $\pi(x) < q(x),$ we should have large $\Delta(x)$, while if $\pi(x) > q(x),$ then $\Delta(x)$ should be small. It's hard to say something very concrete, though: since $D(q|(1-\varepsilon) \pi + \varepsilon \Delta)$ is convex in $\Delta$, the maximisers would lie somewhere on the boundary of the domain, which is hard to characterise in general (i.e., it's hard to [analytically] solve nonconvex opt. problems), so, e.g., the support of $\Delta$ will depend on $(q, \pi)$ in some subtle way.

Do you have any recommendations for defining the boundary given that $p$ should be, at least for the problems I'm interested in, positive (or non-negative), integrate to unity, and, for $\mathbb{R}^n$, be bounded at infinity? I'm unsure how to implement the latter constraint for functional optimization.

Just nonnegativity and finite integral already imply that the function is bounded (in fact, decaying to $0$) at infinity, so you don't really need to worry about that. After that, it's technically just a calculus of variations problem, so you can set up first order conditions, but of course, you'll have to deal with the nonconvexity, which would be difficult. In any case, the salient aspects of the problem should already be evident in discrete+finite support problems, so you might as well study that case in order to gain insights.
